# Bootstrap Tabs - hidden tab's content is still editable

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v3 - I have (2) tabs, with a form in each. The first tab's form is dramatically smaller (in height) than the 2nd. I've tried a couple of different approaches.

Both approaches use the markup below:

```
<div id="container" class="account">
    <header class="clearfix">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#ingresar" data-toggle="tab">Ingresar</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#crear-una-cuenta" data-toggle="tab">Crear una cuenta</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="account-container">
    <div class="tab-content row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="ingresar" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                // form here  ***********
            </div>
            <div id="crear-una-cuenta" class="tab-pane fade">
                // loooooong form here ************
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

You can see in the below fiddle w/ no CSS applied that there is space from the first form above the 2nd form when the 2nd form's tab is active

[See Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/oh40b744/)

Therefore, I added the below CSS, and when the 2nd tab is active, the "empty space" isn't there anymore.

```
.account-container .fade {
    height: 0;
}
    .account-container .fade.in {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

---

Now the space on the 2nd tab is gone. However, the first tab has a ton of space below the form (from the 2nd form that is hidden).

[See Fiddle 2 with CSS applied](http://jsfiddle.net/oh40b744/1/)

I've attempted to duplicate my issue on the fiddle from my localhost, but when the 1st tab is active, you can still highlight the inputs from the hidden 2nd tab, and enter in text.  (see image)

[image]

---

So I attempted to hide the form when the tab isn't active by adding some additional CSS

[Fiddle w/ additional CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/oh40b744/2/)

```
.account-container .fade {
    height: 0;
}

    .account-container .fade form {
        display: none;
    }

    .account-container .fade.in {
        height: 100%;
    }

        .account-container .fade.in form {
            display: block;
        }
```

The issue w/ this is the page jumps b/c these tabs are the only thing on the page (w/ the exception of header, nav, and footer). I then tried to hook into Bootstrap's `show.bs.tab` event to display the form before the tab actually switched, but it didn't work.

**EDIT: - changed jQuery - still didn't work**

```
  $('.account').on('show.bs.tab', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
    $('.account-container').find('div[id="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').find('form').show();
});
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try adding this css line?

```
.tab-pane:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

Here I am setting the display none for those tabs which are not active. This way you don't need any js also.

Comment: was wondering about this - I have the `fade` class applied so the `opacity` was set to 0, but adding this CSS has the same effect. do you need to ALWAYS add this?

Comment: The fade class is basically used for animation with opacity. The opacity describes the transparency-level of an element, so in this case your elements were there but you can't see that. With the latest bootstrap you don't need to add this as they have this fix there

Comment: `.tab-pane:not(.active).show { display: none !important; }` has solved my problem.

Comment: this solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you want here. This is a fiddle which works:
     `<li role="presentation" class="active"> <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>`
http://jsfiddle.net/bepp79jf/

Comment: this would work but I have columns `col-md-8` wrapping the `tab-pane` elements  see http://jsfiddle.net/bepp79jf/1/